# ActionScript - Read Only Property and Private Set Method?

Tags: actionscript-3, private, getter-setter

one thing i've never really understood about AS3 is that you can't have a private set method and a public get method together.

from within my class i would like to assign values that would call a private set function:

`myNumber = 22`;

but i need to pass that number as a parameter to a function

```
myNumber(22);
```

for example:

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.Sprite

//Class
public class NumberClass extends Sprite
    {
    //Properties
    private var myNumberProperty:Number

    //Constructor
    public function NumberClass(myNumber:Number):void
        {
        this.myNumber = myNumber;

        init();
        }

    //Initialize
    private function init():void
        {
        trace(myNumber);
        }

    //My Number Setter
    private function set myNumber(value:Number):void
        {
        myNumberProperty = Math.max(0, Math.min(value, 100));
        }

    //My Number Getter
    public function get myNumber():Number
        {
        return myNumberProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

is there no way to use the set keyword on a private function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MXML compiler does not support getters and setters with mixed scopes/namespaces. There are a few tickets open regarding this:

- https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASL-44
- https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25646
- https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASL-112.

It's quite annoying, but at least Adobe is aware of it.  There is a way to accomplish mixed namespace getters and setters by using custom namespaces and fully-qualifying references to the getter or setter.

```
package {

    use namespace my_namespace

    public class MyClass {

        private var _name:String;

        public function get name():String {
            return _name;
        }

        my_namespace function set name(value:String):void {
            _name = value;
        }
     }

     public class MySubClass extends MyClass {

       public function MySubClass(name:String) {
           super.my_namespace::name = name;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it certainly is an annoyance.  hopefully it will be corrected sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason

```
private function set myNumber(value:Number):void
{
    myNumberProperty = value;
}
```

doesn't work?  What error does it give?  I've done this all the time in Flex, so I'm not sure if it only works there... I wouldn't think so, though.

edit: Looks like this is a compiler bug.  Here's a blog post with the solution http://blogagic.com/230/struggling-with-flex-error-1000-ambiguous-reference-to

Comment: i get 2 compile time errors:  1.  1059: Property is read-only.  2.  1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property myNumber through a reference with static type NumberClass.  i'm using Flash Professional CS5.

Comment: it's a bug that's been around since 2006 at least. It doesn't seem a high priority for Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but could you just create a private method?

Comment: absolutely, but i just don't like doing that since, as i mentioned, i requires passing a value rather than assigning one.  i always keep my setters and getters grouped at the bottom of my class and i'd just prefer if i could use the set keyword.  but besides being picky, i just think it doesn't make sense to not allow it since the access modifiers are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
> is there no way to use the set keyword
> on a private function?<br/>
```

Nope If one is private they both have to be private. Regardless of what others think this is not a bug.

The idea behind setters/getters is to **isolate code** from the **public**.
Remember this OOP
You should also try to stay with typical convention for the var name with a leading _

```
private var _myNumber:Number

// private assessor/assignor 
  private function set number(value:Number):void{
    this._myNumber= Math.max(0, Math.min(value, 100));
  }
  private function get number():void{
    return this._myNumber;
  }


// public assessor
  public function get myNumber():Number{
    return this._myNumber;
  }
```

[refer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=basic_as_2.html)
[The so called bug report is here](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-4118)

Comment: *gasp*  the leading underscore is certainly no longer a convention as it was in the old days of AS2.  might i also add that's it's seriously ugly and ghetto.  lol.  sorry, but i am passionately against the leading underscore to mark variables.  but getting back on topic, i believe it's the job of the access modifiers to isolate code.

Comment: Assessors and assignors are always set both public or both private or whatever. I could only imagine what the compiler team would have to do to change this to what you want. As for conventions if you looked at the link above you would most definitely see that adobe states this is the standard convention. Ghetto or not this is how it is done over many languages get used to it. When you don't follow set language standards the other people working with your code will have that much of a harder time understanding already cryptic coding. You don't code for yourself, you code for others.

Comment: it's a choice of style.  the underscore is (an old nasty habit) left over from AS2 when all objects had ugly._underscore properties.  nor do i cuddle my functions like you, as it too is ugly in addition to being factually more difficult to read, cryptic, especially for new developers.  i do, however, write my constants in all caps and underscores and believe in writing in camelCase, but not everyone follows nor should be obliged to code the same way just because of some unnecessary conventions and just because some developers believe that their old habits help in managing efficient team work.

Comment: Again it is not an old nasty habit, it is convention as set forth by the developers of the language. You don't have to agree with it, but it is the standard