# ActionScript - Determine A Caller's Class?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, function, call, public

since the [MXMLC compiler doesn't support mixed access modifiers for setters/getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465793/actionscript-read-only-property-and-private-set-method), i would like to know whether a public setter function is being called from inside or outside of the setter's class.  this approach should allow me to maintain a public property but with more security, something like public/private hybrid access.

is it possible to use arguments' callee property, or perhaps something else, to determine whether the setter was set internally from the setter's class or if it was set externally?

here's an example of what i mean:

```
package
{
//Class
public class MyLocation
    {
    //Constants
    public static const LOCATION_LEFT:String = "locationLeft";
    public static const LOCATION_RIGHT:String = "locationRight";

    //Properties
    private var sideLocationProperty:String;

    //Constructor
    public function MyLocation(sideLocation:String = MyLocation.LOCATION_LEFT)
        {
        this.sideLocation = sideLocation;

        trace(sideLocation);
        }

    //Texture Panel Is Collapsed Setter
    public function set sideLocation(value:String):void
        {
        if  (value != LOCATION_LEFT && value != LOCATION_RIGHT && value != LOCATION_AUTO)
            throw new ArgumentError("\"MyLocation set sideLocation(value:String)\" – value parameter is not supported.");

        sideLocationProperty = value;

        //pseudo code
        if  (arguments.callee is from MyLocation)
            trace("sideLocation was set internally");
            else
            trace("sideLocation was set externally");
        }

    //Texture Panel Is Collapsed Getter
    public function get sideLocation():String
        {
        return sideLocationProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you can't do that.

Why don't you write

```
public function setSideLocation(value:String, caller:* = null):void
```

then you can do whatever you want to do with it, like

```
trace(caller is MovieClip);
```

or `caller.hasOwnProperty(something)`

etc.

By setting it to null as a default value, you don't even need to use it. Just optionally.

So to call it from another object do:

```
object.setSideLocation("something", this);
```

Also to keep it consistent write

`public function getSideLocation():String`.

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible.

Also, it's a really bad idea. try to keep your code free of side-effects, ie. you shouldn't write code that deliberately or accidentally performs differently because of the Class of the caller. Imagine trying to unit-test such code - nightmare.

Comment: you're right.  that would be a nightmare.  i guess i only wanted to share the setter so i could use the same code to validate the property value, but i've refactored the class another way so to avoid this.  thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, AS3 getters and setters are already flexible enough to make it easy to write difficult-to-follow code by making them unexpected side effects, and this idea would just make it even more confusing. The whole point of a getter or setter is to provide a controlled public access point--there is no need to call a getter or setter from within the class that has access to the private members.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old questions but if someone else is looking... try the following and parse the stack trace to get the caller

> trace( new Error().getStackTrace() )